# Triangulating the surface of intersection of a sphere with edges of a cube

Tags: geometry, circles, 3d

I want to triangulate the surface of intersection of a sphere with edges of a cube(image below). When number of intersection points > 3, the points are non-coplanar and the triangulations are non-unique. As of now I am planning to calculate the centroid of the intersection points and triangulate them with the centroid as the common vertex. (I am open to other triangulation choices).For this the pre-requisite is that the points are arranged in C.C.W. order.

[image]

I tried fitting a plane to the non-coplanar points, project the 3D points onto the plane and sort the points on the plane. This process is slow because a least square plane has to be fit to the points. Also when some intercepts are close to each-other, the plane normal is biased and I end up getting wrong order sometimes. There are also situations where an edge has more than one intercept, where this triangulation fails to work

Is there a simple and fool proof way to do this.

thanks

Comment: When you say "cube" or "sphere", do you mean a surface or the interior of a surface? If a surface, the intersection of the two surfaces consists of a finite number of closed curves. If interiors, the intersection is the convex interior of another surface. The number of intersection points is either $0$, $1$, or uncountably infinite, so it is unclear why "$>3$" is a criterion for anything. In what sense are triangulations of a surface ever unique?

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to say that I have a cubic wireframe(only edges of the cube) and a sphere surface is intersecting the wireframe. I have corrected this in the question. About the triangulation, with 3 points a unique triangle can be formed, more than 3 points we may have more than one way of forming triangles

Comment: If you're just concerned about the red surface in the figure, then (mathematically) you have the intersection of the sphere (surface) with the interior of the cube.

Comment: Is the center of the sphere on the (continuation of) big diagonal of the cube ? Said otherwise, is your piece of surface invariant by a $2 \pi/3$ rotation around this big diagonal ?

Comment: If you have the longitude and the (co)latitude of the following 4 points : the 3 intersection points + the point where the big axis of the cube intersects the sphere, you can build a triangulation.